# Find all instances where someone is running user

Tags: visual-workflow, query, user, process-automation, deactivate

I am trying to help someone remove all instances where a specific person has left the company is the running user in Salesforce. I would not consider myself a developer by any means, however this sounds like a developer question.

I went through scheduled jobs and rescheduled and have been watching apex jobs to see what is under his name. Now I have started to look at all the process automations and I thought, there has to be a better way to locate everything. So my question is two-fold:

1. Is there a "simple" way I can locate all instances where he is the running user.. so that we can deactivate him?
2. IS there an easy way to let's say change him as the running user of a flow? Some programmatic find and replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of approaches

### Use your IDE

Download all of the org's metadata into a project and then scan for that user. And when I say all, I mean all, including `Settings`

### Rifle Shot

- `Setup > Process Automated Settings > Default Workflow User` ([Flows](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2022/your-guide-to-determining-the-flow-running-user-and-its-execution-context#:%7E:text=The%20running%20user%20of%20a,run%20as%20the%20current%20user.)); otherwise, it is the user that submitted the flow and if person is gone, is no longer submitting flows
- `Setup > Support Settings > Automated Case User` (Email-to-Case, Assignment Rules, Escalation Rules)
- `Setup > Lead Settings > Default Lead Owner` - not technically a running user but should be checked; same for `Support Settings > Default Case Owner`
- Platform Events - the [trigger subscribers can be configured to run in the context of a user](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_platformeventsubscriberconfig.htm) that is different than the default Automated Process user
- Connected Apps - if configured to run with [Client Credentials](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_client_credentials_flow.htm&type=5), the app will run always as a specific user
- `Setup > Scheduled Jobs` - this would include Apex Schedulable as well as scheduled reports.
- `Setup > OAuth Usage` - you can see who is using which Connected App via OAuth connections

.. and I'm sure I've missed some, especially for features my orgs have not licensed.

Comment: Love the grouping of Rifle Shot.. good laugh.. 

I have no idea how to download the metadata.. help please.. 

As far as scheduled jobs.. I already did that manually.. Found some flows so I am wondering there 

Looks like he downloaded Classy and is the OAuth which I know nothing about Classy - that would be connected apps no???

So maybe I need to download visual studio?

Comment: VsCode would be an appropriate IDE; I use Illuminated Cloud; You could also use a tool like Gearset or Copado to get all the Metadata and download as a package.xml. Classy is an appExchange product and often admins configure the integration to use their own credentials rather than a service account user that is invariant, not subject to quitting/termination/retiring.  You could see which records were created by said user to help see if Classy is culprit

Comment: Hmmm.. I will have to look this up.. I have heard Gearset is awesome for comparing environments too, so I will have to check it out. Classy is definitely ONE of the culprits as he had a data sync job that i cannot seem to redo which will be an investigation.. but after seeing that I know there are other things.. 

Ok.. I may circle back here when I am lost again. but I appreciate the answer and the help